# Need to Add SPF Record

Tags: spf, mx-record

We had the warning about spf containing to many lookups. Deleted
txt ourdomainname.com v=spf1 ip4:50.87.253.89 a mx include:websitewelcome.com ~all as we are no longer on bluehost which the ip references.

Hosted on siteground but use cloudflare dns and use gmail to send mail through our domain.

[current mx records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtxoG.png)

Cleaned up references of SRV _caldavs._tcp entries related to an old bluehost blue rock account also. Important to get in a new accurate SPF record that does not cause the too many lookups error again.

Should the new SPF record be as follows? I am not sure. Appreciate suggestions.

TXT ourdomainname.com v=spf1 mx ~all

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Google Workspace support article: https://support.google.com/a/answer/10685031?hl=en

The solution for sending mail through Google Workspace is as follows:

`v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all`

Comment: Thanks Aidan! Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: @Kimberly Can you please mark my answer as the correct solution if it solved your problem?